# Smarty Resource directory

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I'm using smarty for my latest personal project and run into a problem.

```
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->template_dir = 'templates/dashboard/';
```

The above makes load .tpl files from this directory, this works great for me, but inside the .tpl i want to load an image and i have to do:

```
<img src="templates/dashboard/images/avatar/full/{$user->username}.jpg" class="profile-avatar img-thumbnail">
```

What i would like to do but won't work is:

```
<img src="images/avatar/full/{$user->username}.jpg" class="profile-avatar img-thumbnail">
```

I tought when i set the template_dir this would also change but it doesn't...
I couldn't find any documentation where i can change this for the .tpl file.

**note the 'templates/dashboard', that's what i want to get rid of inside the .tpl**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is you should not put images in the same folder where you have your templates. Images should be put in public folder (usually `public` or `public_html`) and site code can be places in other directory that is not accessible from web.

So move your files into another folder because the structure you have now will definitely get you in trouble some day.

But if you still want to use such structure, you could simply assign new variable to Smarty with the path you want to use:

```
$smarty->assign('ip', $smarty->template_dir);
```

and now in your template you can use:

```
<img src="{$ip}images/avatar/full/{$user->username}.jpg" class="profile-avatar img-thumbnail">
```